# How to keep data after headless browser selenium tests are passed?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, bamboo

Currently, we are using `selenium` for the automation test within our projects. We are using `PhantomJs WebDriver` to be able to run headless browser tests on bamboo. We want to be able to see the data(or content) which are created and saved by tests using `PhantomJs` but looks like the content will be gone after that tests are passed.

If we run the tests on Firefox driver without `PhantomJs`, we can see the content (or data) which is created by tests.

How we could config `Phantomjs WebDriver` in `selenium` to be able to see new content (or data) after running tests?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Explain content please.

Comment: @Saifur Our system is based on a content repository and every content can be an asset in our system.

Comment: I understand that. But not sure what you meant by you don't see data. Can you be little more specific please?

Comment: @Saifur when we run the tests with firfox driver, it create and save new content in the repository and it is visible to search and read or update the content afterwards. But when we run the tests with phantomjs web driver, tests will be passed while the content which are created and saved are not visible. it looks like it never created them.